# Dynamically access deeply nested object properties by splitting a string with dot separators

Tags: javascript, json

Consider the following JSON object:

```
{
    "data": {
        "data2": {
            "myProp": "hello"
        }
    }
}
```

I need to be able to dynamically access the deep property `myProp`, but the catch is, that I need to be able to write the deep property as a regular string. i.e:

```
let sortByThisValue = 'data.data2.myProp'
```

So I already started:

```
let propertyArray = sortByThisValue.split('.')
//Do something here
let myVal = data.[data2][myProp] //Or data.data2.myProp
```

Comment: What if one of the property names includes a dot `.`?

Answer (score 1):

You can access like below

```js
const obj = {
  data: {
    data2: {
      myProp: "hello",
    },
  },
};

const key = "data.data2.myProp";

const getValue = (obj, key) => {
  const keys = key.split(".");
  let value = obj;
  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    value = value[keys[i]];
    if (!value) {
       break;
    }
  }
  return value;
};


console.log(getValue(obj, key));
console.log(getValue(obj, 'abc'));
```